# Three.JS Collada Model Size Memory Issues

Tags: memory, three.js, collada

I am curious as to what the expected size in memory would be for a simple scene with a 3MB model loaded in using the ColladaLoader.js. (The model was initially a sketchup file, converted to .dae)

Currently when I load in my 3MB .dae model file into the scene & profile by taking a heap snapshot, my scene is at 118MB! (The model is the only thing in the scene.)

I believe a memory leak is the culprit. But I also can't find any information on what I should expect the size to be. I read Collada files are expensive, bandwidth-wise, but can someone give me a realistic example of what memory usage to expect?

(I'm using three.js r69)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the ColladaLoader convert the geometry into an Array, 3MB of Informations is a huge Array. I got 6 100KB Models in my Scene, but the Head Snapshot give a size of 31MB.

Comment: Thanks that gives me some perspective. Is there a good way to reduce the file size of Collada files?

Comment: The size of every Object grown by the amount of the vertices/faces. If you got a high amoung of edges and curves Three.js will create that amount of vertices per Edge, a lot of vertices for every single curve. And connect all with a lot of faces. All in all: A lot of everything. Try to create your Models without perfect curves, not that much edges and so on.